# jQuery hover doesn't seem to be perfect

Tags: jquery

I basically have a sidebar flyout menu. I made it using jQuery hover. However, I am having a couple of problems. If I am hovering over an element, and I quickly move off the screen and onto the browser, the onmouseleave never actually fires and the element stays there. On the other hand, if I am hovering over an element and I refresh the page (while leaving my mouse there), the onmouseenter doesn't fire until I leave the element and enter it again.

I know I can use CSS hover but I would like some animation with the flyouts (like fading in, delays etc.)

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use css3 transitions for animations.

Example: http://css3.bradshawenterprises.com/cfimg1/

Comment: I might agree, but does every visitor to your site?  Websites usually *have to* support almost all users, most clients accept nothing less.

Comment: they're not loosing accessibility or functionality, just aesthetics.

Comment: Aye, but many people might not like their website to vary between browsers that much.

Comment: Css3 transitions are fine and all but is it possible to solve the problems I put forth using jquery/javascript?

Comment: for the refresh problem you can use the `mousemove` event.